# How to know if shared host (GoDaddy) supports ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, shared-hosting

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to deploy a Web API application on GoDaddy but could not find a good answer. The closest I came was this link:

http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/go-daddy-compatible-with-asp-net-mvc-4-razor-syntaxe/

Is there a way I can tell if a shared host supports ASP.NET Web API?

Comment: Just to be clear it does support asp.net 4.0 and web aoi can be used independently so I am not sure if I can deploy web api applications on go daddy or not

Comment: Yes Go Daddy shared hosting will support MVC 4 and Web API, one thing to consider is shared hosting on Go Daddy does not support Full-Trust, you can run into a wall there when trying to use certain other libraries which are available via NuGet.  Make sure any additional nugets your running such as ORM peristence frameworks and  IoC containers, and plugins will run in a partial trust environment.

Comment: Yeah, that's the reason I stepped up to a VPS server, it gives you full trust access.  I didn't go with GoDaddy for the VPS, but don't really want to get into a marketing thing...just make sure your environment will support full trust if your going need it.  It took me for ever to debug why my application wouldn't start up in the shared hosting environment (no system logs)

Comment: Thanks you have saved me a lot of potential head ache :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Comment: This question might be more useful if it was phrased as "What do I need to make sure my hosting provider supports to deploy a ASP.NET WebAPI?"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In practice, there is no concept as ASP.NET Web API support in terms of hosting. What you should really be doing is to install the [ASP.NET Web API NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi) into your project and the assemblies you get through this package are bin deployable.

In terms of hosting, What you need to be looking for on your hosting options is the support for IIS 7 or higher (I don't think IIS 6 is supported but I am not sure), .NET 4.0 or higher (the higher is .NET 4.5 now) and Integrated Application Pool availability. If you have those, an ASP.NET Web API application should run without any problems under IIS.

If you ask the hosting provider for support for ASP.NET Web API, it is likely that they won't know the answer. Instead, you can ask for the features that I listed above.

Comment: Can you please let me know which are the dlls to include?

Answer (score 2):

If it supports MVC4 I think it us unlikely WebAPI wouldn't work.

Comment: @Rab, because if it runs .NET 4/4.5 then you can bin deploy the rest of the requirements.