# Hosting a .NET Core Web API in Shared Hosting

Tags: .net

I have a simple .Net Core Web API and I pushed all my files to www.rosenet.om root directry and trying to access it http://rosenet.om/api/data/tiles (data is my controller and tiles is my method) but I can't. I get this message

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702452/how-to-know-if-shared-host-godaddy-supports-asp-net-web-api

Comment: https://forums.asp.net/t/1239943.aspx?How+to+deploy+MVC+app+to+shared+hosting+